# infix notation in Lean

Tags: lean

Is there an infix notation that would allow to rewrite those proofs

```
example (h₀ : a ≤ b) (h₁ : b < c) (h₂ : c ≤ d) (h₃ : d < e) :
  a < e := lt_trans (lt_of_lt_of_le (lt_of_le_of_lt (h₀) h₁) h₂ ) h₃

example (h₀ : a ≤ b) (h₁ : b < c) (h₂ : c ≤ d) (h₃ : d < e) :
  a < e := by
  { apply lt_trans,
    {apply lt_of_lt_of_le, 
      {apply lt_of_le_of_lt, apply h₀, apply h₁}
     , apply h₂},
    apply h₃
 }
```

more naturally as

```
example (h₀ : a ≤ b) (h₁ : b < c) (h₂ : c ≤ d) (h₃ : d < e) :
  a < e := ((h₀ `lt_of_le_of_lt` h₁) `lt_of_lt_of_le` h₂) `lt_trans` h₃
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Lean's dot notation to make an infix version of the argument, for example

```
example (h₀ : a ≤ b) (h₁ : b < c) (h₂ : c ≤ d) (h₃ : d < e) :
  a < e :=  (h₀.trans_lt h₁).trans (h₂.trans_lt h₃)
```

What's going on here is that the type of `h₀` is `le a b` (in the `has_le` namespace), so `h₀.trans_lt` means `le.trans_lt h₀`, and you can see in `order.basic` in mathlib that `le.trans_lt` is just an abbreviation for `lt_of_le_of_lt`.

Comment: Thank you for the pedagogical explanation. I should RTFM (theorem proving + mathlib ) first but it hurted my eyes already and I had to know it could be done..

Comment: Just to be pedantic, `h₀.trans_lt` means `h₀ |> le.trans_lt` which itself means `le.trans_lt h₀` . the dot notation does two things : it changes the conventional mathematical composition to natural composition (which is regrettably not the same). and it also seem to scope operation. nice on both account

Comment: I think you now know more about dot notation than I do :-)

Comment: Transforming `h₀.trans_lt h₁` to `h₀ |> le.trans_lt h₁` is not really a better version of the rule that Kevin wrote; dot notation doesn't always populate the left argument, it uses the leftmost argument that typechecks. So `foo.bar x y z` sometimes means `Foo.bar x y foo z`.

Comment: @Eric interesting thanks for the precision. [ I spelled it out for future reader - probably future me ]